# How to make the run time of the program to ϴ n

Tags: algorithm, loops, time-complexity, pseudocode

The requirement is that the input will be set of integer ranging from -5 to 5, the result should give the longest subset of the integer, in which the total must be greater or equal to zero.

I can only come up with the following:
The input will be input[0 to n]

```
let start, longestStart, end, longestEnd, sum = 0

for i=0 to n-1
start = i
sum = input[i]
  for j=1 to n
  if sum + input[j] >= 0 then 
    end=j;
  if end - start > longestEnd - longestStart then
    longestStart = start;
    longestEnd = end;
```

However this is ϴ(n^2). I would like to know what are the ways to make this loop become ϴ(n)
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since

```
a - b == (a + n) - (b + n)
```

for any a, b or n, we can apply this to the array of numbers, keeping a running total of all elements from 0 to current. From the above equation, the sum of any subarray from index a to b is sum(elements 0-b) - sum(elements 0-a).

By keeping track of local minima and maxima, and the sums to them, you can find the subarray with the greatest range in one pass, ie O(n).

Comment: Thank you for answering. I am still a little bit confused. If I have an input with [1, 2, 3, -5, 4, 3, -1] and the sum of this array is [1, 3, 6, 1, 5, 8, 7]. It is obvious that the whole array is the longest subarray, but how do I obtain it with the local minima and maxima?

Comment: @swordgit: for your example isn't the whole array you are looking for an answer? You asked longest subset of the integer whose sum is greater or equal to zero.